# How to get a vector/array output from a loop within a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
def solve_V(r,H,h):
    for i in h.tolist():
        if i<=r:
            const1=math.pi*(1/3)
            sqr=i**2
            radh=3*r-i
            V=const1*sqr*radh
        elif H+r>i>r:
            const2=2*(math.pi/3)
            radc=r**3
            radsq=r**2
            V=const2*radc+math.pi*radsq*(i-r)
    return [V]
print(solve_V(2.5,12,np.linspace(0,H,9)))
```

this is meant to give me all the values of V for the h array, however only one value is in the output which is for the largest value of h in the array

Comment: You can append to a list, then return it. It might be better to just use a list comprehension and write a function that computes one item V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you overwriting the value of `V` on every iteration of your loop, and finally `return [V]` returns an array with a single element.

Instead what you want to do is append to an array for each iteration of the loop. For example:

```py
def solve_V(r,H,h):
    vs = [] #<-- Empty list to hold all your Vs
    for i in h.tolist():
        if i<=r:
            const1=math.pi*(1/3)
            sqr=i**2
            radh=3*r-i
            V=const1*sqr*radh
            vs.append(V)#<--- Add the V for this iteration to the list
        elif H+r>i>r:
            const2=2*(math.pi/3)
            radc=r**3
            radsq=r**2
            V=const2*radc+math.pi*radsq*(i-r)
            vs.append(v) #<-- Same here, just adding the new V to the list
    return vs #<-- Return all the Vs. 
print(solve_V(2.5,12,np.linspace(0,H,9)))
```